# export view daterange to excel

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to export a view daterange to excel, but it seems the notesviewentry is always empty.
My code :

```
var vDateRange = session.createDateRange(sessionScope.selectedStartDate, sessionScope.selectedEndDate);
var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
var response = exCon.getResponse();
var projects:NotesView = database.getView('visits_by_date_VB')
var viewNav:NotesViewNavigator = projects.createViewNav();
var viewEnt:NotesViewEntry = viewNav.getEntryByKey([vDateRange]);
var output:string = "";
while (viewEnt != null) {
 output += "<tr>";
 output += "<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[0]; + "</td>";
 output += "<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[1] + "</td>";
 output += "<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2] + "</td>";
 output += "<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[3] + "</td>";
 output += "<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[4] + "</td>";
 output += "</tr>";
viewEnt = viewNav.getNext(viewEnt);
}
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=export.xls");
writer.write("<table>");
writer.write("<thead><tr>");
writer.write("<td><b>Branch Id</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Company Name</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Share value</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>City</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Country</b></td>");
writer.write("</tr></thead>");
writer.write(output);
writer.write("</table>");
writer.endDocument();
```

The sessionScope's are not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get an entry based on a range, rather than getting all entries between the range. Try:

```
var viewEntryCollection:NotesViewEntryCollection = projects.getAllEntriesByKey([vDateRange]);
var viewEnt:NotesViewEntry = viewEntryCollection.getFirstEntry();
```

Comment: Paul, thanks, that did it. I also had to remove the [ ] around the vDateRange

Comment: is it possible to add an excel formulae in a cell ?

Comment: Not sure. If you want something beyond the basic, I'd recommend Apache POI. The documentation is very good and if you've done integration with Excel or Word via LotusScript or some other scripting language, it's easy to pick up.